# Logging shows wrong linenumber

Tags: python-2.7

Im trying to learn python 2.7s logging module, and have copied this clip:

def _logging():
    # set up program logging
    global logger

```
# valid logging levels:
# =====================
# logger.debug('debug message')
# logger.info('info message')
# logger.warn('warn message')
# logger.error('error message')
# logger.critical('critical message')
#
# to show traceback:
# logger.critical(str(e), exc_info = True)   # if 'error' & 'True' - halts script 

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create file handler which logs INFO & above messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('c:/temp/pgmLog.log','w')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create console handler that logs all messages
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s   %(lineno)-5d %(levelname)-12s %(message)s', datefmt='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)       # console logger
logger.addHandler(fh)       # file logger
```

when I run the following piece:

```html
logger.info('Program start')
try:
    print 3/0
except Exception, err:
    logger.error(err)
```

the logger is showing me:

```html
11-22-2014 15:48:32   46    INFO         Program start
11-22-2014 15:48:32   1415  ERROR        integer division or modulo by zero
```

Can someone please tell me why the error is showing as line 1415, and not the real location of the error?

Many thanks

Comment: Copying and pasting your code shows no strange line number here. (Python 2.7.8 on Linux.) Is this really all the code you're running when you see the problem? What's the minimum amount of code that you can run that will show this problem?

Comment: Web search shows this person seeing a very similar error: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2006-November/050646.html

Comment: Looks like that was a similar bug that was fixed in 2007: https://bugs.python.org/issue1652788 What version of Python exactly are you running?

Comment: Yes, this is all the code.  All you need to see the problem is: 'print 3/0'.  The line number may vary with different errors.  I neglected to try.  I will check out the other links listed.  Thanks for your input!  I'm using Python 2.7.8

Comment: Ok, in that case I think this is probably a bug. You should check your version of Python you're using, and upgrade the version and/or report the bug: http://bugs.python.org/

Comment: Trying the link in your second post DOES add the complete traceback showing the real line number in addition to the reference to line 1415.  I will follow your advice and try bugs.python.org.